# Why does my Conditional Formatting fail when it works in Worksheet? Possible INDIRECT issue?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, excel-indirect

I am trying to do a comparison/Conditional Formatting between columns based on a drop-down choice.  I have a formula that works fine in the spreadsheet, but does not seem to be working in my Conditional Formatting formula.  Is INDIRECT causing my issue?

Formula is:

```
=IF(H1>100, IF((H1-INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(H1), MATCH($H$4,$A$3:$I$3,0))))/((H1+INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(H1), MATCH($H$4,$A$3:$I$3,0))))/2)>$J$2,TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)
```

Kind of hard to read, but the part that broke it is trying to grab my comparison  cell using the following:

```
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(H1), MATCH($H$4,$A$3:$I$3,0)))
```

Where $H$4 is my drop-down value.  So I am selecting the column that contains the data I want to compare to, then using address to select the current rows cell, then accessing it with INDIRECT.

If I replace the INDIRECT part with an actual cell, everything works as it should as well.

When I use the first formula, everything looks great if I input it into a cell on the worksheet, but I would rather not dirty it up if I don't have to.  Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Try: `INDEX($A:$I,row(1:1),MATCH($H$4,$A$3:$I$3,0)` in place of the indirects.

Comment: Scott, that was it!  Thank you very much!